# pointer to a array of initialized integers

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to declare a pointer to a array of initialized ints at once(gcc 5.2.0, gnu99)

This is working

```
int a1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int (*a)[] = &a1;
```

I tried this and it isn't

```
int *why = (int p[2]) {1,2};

../src/gps/gps.c:399:18: error: expected ')' before 'p'
  int *why = (int p[2]) {1,2};
                  ^

int (*b)[5]= (int(*)[5])&({11,2,3,5,6});

../src/gps/gps.c:400:31: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
  int (*b)[5]= (int(*)[5])&({11,2,3,5,6});
                           ^
int (*cc)[] = &{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
../src/gps/gps.c:402:17: error: expected expression before '{' token
  int (*cc)[] = &{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
                 ^
```

What I miss here?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but does `int (*a)[] = &{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` do anything?

Comment: You should show the code first then the error messages that the code causes.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line of code: `int *why = (int p[2]) {1,2};`? This is not correct C syntax as the error message tells you.

Comment: It was just a answer from StackOverflow that supposed to work :) (some old thread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the proper way to define these:

```
int *why = (int [2]) {1,2};
int (*a)[5]= &((int []){11,2,3,5,6});
```

When you create a *compound literal*, you prefix it with what looks like a typecast.

The first line didn't work because you attempted to put a variable name inside of the cast, and the second line didn't work because you didn't put the cast immediately before the part in curly braces.

Comment: I don't think the second line needs the `(int[])` cast.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - It's not a cast, it's a compound literal expression. Without it, the initializer has no inherent meaning.